# MediaControllerCompat.Callback onAudioInfoChanged never gets called

Tags: android, audio

I'm using my own volume controller:

```
        xenoVolumeProvider = new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_RELATIVE, maxXenoVolume, XenoAmp.getAndSetPref("xenoVol", maxXenoVolume / 2)) {
            @Override
            public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                super.onAdjustVolume(direction);
                actionSetVolumeByTick(direction);
                //Logger.d("Wart vol=" + mSession.getController().getPlaybackInfo().getCurrentVolume());
            }
        };
        mSession.setPlaybackToRemote(xenoVolumeProvider);
```

While it (surprisingly) works as expected (apart from a bug on Android 4 that causes FC, unsurprisingly) MediaControllerCompat.Callback's onAudioInfoChanged never gets called, although all other callbacks do.

Since Google's MediaController/MediaSession documentation is (unsurprisingly) non-existant maybe I'm missing something. Maybe I should somehow call onAudioInfoChanged myself on each volume change, but HOW?

There's this callback, that works:

```
        xenoVolumeProvider.setCallback(new VolumeProviderCompat.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onVolumeChanged(VolumeProviderCompat volumeProvider) {
                // maybe I can call onAudioInfoChanged from here?
            }
        });
```

but then again how would I call MediaControllerCompat.Callback's onAudioInfoChanged from there? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your `onAdjustVolume()` is an indicator that a volume adjust request has been submitted - to get the callbacks, make sure you call [setCurrentVolume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat.html#setCurrentVolume(int)) from within your `onAdjustVolume()` method. As per the Javadoc, that method:

> Set the current volume and **notify the system that the volume has been changed.**

Note: as per the docs on [setCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/VolumeProviderCompat.html#setCallback(android.support.v4.media.VolumeProviderCompat.Callback)), this is used internally in the support library - you shouldn't set your own callback as it will override the `MediaSessionCompat`'s Callback that is set when you call `setPlaybackToRemote()`, causing the callbacks to not propagate to any controllers.

Comment: Well, suspecting that it works this way, setCurrentVolume() is called by actionSetVolumeByTick(direction) and the volume of the controller is set properly (plus it pops up on the screen when I set flag to show GUI), yet I would just liike to receive notification that volume was changed, because I use my own indicator for that. OnAudioInfoChanged never gets called. Should I use any other callback then?

Comment: Just to confirm, what version of the support library are you using? As long as you don't use `setCallback()`, the default behavior of `MediaSessionCompat` should be forwarding it onto your MediaController

Comment: I really can't afford to use any versions besides the top ones (guess why?...) 23.0.1, of course. I only setCallback on my m\MediaController and my VolumeProviderCompat. Which callback is a no-no?

Comment: The `VolumeProviderCompat.setCallback()` is the one you shouldn't use.

Comment: I've removed this callback aaaaand... Here goes nothing! onAudioInfoChanged of my MediaController is still not called (anyway - the callback wasn't there before, I've added it later thinking that maybe I can call onAudioInfoChanged from there...) So... do you have any more ideas? Or piece of working code that calls onAudioInfoChanged?